# Polygon splitting and merging to another one without overlapping using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, merge, splitting, donut-polygons

I have a layer of different types of polygons. Some are fields, other are roads. Sometime a road polygon is entering a field polygon. As presented on the capture, the yellow road (polygon 1) is getting inside the blue field (polygon 2).

I am trying to split the road in 2 pieces 1A and 1B, at their edges intersection (following the red line), so I could then merge and dissolve the part 1A of the road to the field (polygon 2) it is contained within.

The goal is to have a layer with only fields polygons. Roads should be erased, and all gaps filled and merged to the largest adjacent polygon.

As there are no overlapping, I was looking of a way to cut/split the road polygon, before merging it to the fields. But as there is a very important amount of data, this process should be done automatically, and not manually by identifying visually edges and splitting using polylines.

Is there a way you can think of, using ArcGIS tools (perhaps production mapping?) or any other tool or method that I could use?

[image]

Comment: Create triangles inside densified roads and join them spatially to others - share line segment with.

Comment: Is the red line available in another feature class?  Are you saying that there is currently no cyan field polygon underneath the yellow road?  With no answers offered I think you need to keep editing your question to try and make what you asking clearer.

Comment: You have a tag for [tag:donut-polygons] but I see no mention of donut polygons in your question.